# Submit Captcha correctly and close my floating popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, popup

I have a flying popup that loads when page loads and closes when I hit "close"
I want to add a form into this popup to submit Captcha correctly and close my floating popup. I found "hidePopup();" inside the Javascript as the closing function. and I tried the following but every time I submit my form, page reloads and popup appears. I want popup just closes when I hit "submit" without page reloading
My code

```
<form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6Ldgse4SAAAAANV-J3bHQbm75XukolyZclhvJfIy">
  </script>
<noscript>
     <iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=6Ldgse4SAAAAANV-J3bHQbm75XukolyZclhvJfIy" height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br/>
<textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40">
     </textarea>
<input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" 
 value="manual_challenge" /></noscript>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="hidePopup();" />
</form>
```

See my popup live there http://www.refinerypedia.uni.me/

Comment: edit your `hidepopup` function and add `return false` at the end.

Comment: There is a problem with the submit button...when you press Submit, it reloads the entire page, so your popup is loaded again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- I have to return false inside the form attribute "onsubmit"

```
<form onsubmit="return false;">
```

2- I need to use Cookies to store some info about the form status (Is it submitted before or not). See [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

3- I should then submit the form programatically using [Form submit() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_submit.asp)